# What does enumerate() mean?

Tags: python, enumerate

What does `for row_number, row in enumerate(cursor):` do in Python?

What does `enumerate` mean in this context?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 537):

The [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) adds a counter to an iterable.

So for each element in `cursor`, a tuple is produced with `(counter, element)`; the `for` loop binds that to `row_number` and `row`, respectively.

Demo:

```
>>> elements = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
>>> for elem in elements:
...     print elem
... 
foo
bar
baz
>>> for count, elem in enumerate(elements):
...     print count, elem
... 
0 foo
1 bar
2 baz
```

By default, `enumerate()` starts counting at `0` but if you give it a second integer argument, it'll start from that number instead:

```
>>> for count, elem in enumerate(elements, 42):
...     print count, elem
... 
42 foo
43 bar
44 baz
```

If you were to re-implement `enumerate()` in Python, here are two ways of achieving that; one using [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to do the counting, the other manually counting in a [generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do):

```
from itertools import count

def enumerate(it, start=0):
    # return an iterator that adds a counter to each element of it
    return zip(count(start), it)
```

and

```
def enumerate(it, start=0):
    count = start
    for elem in it:
        yield (count, elem)
        count += 1
```

The [actual implementation in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/enumobject.c) is closer to the latter, with optimisations to reuse a single tuple object for the common `for i, ...` unpacking case and using a standard C integer value for the counter until the counter becomes too large to avoid using a Python integer object (which is unbounded).

Answer (score 98):

It's a builtin function that returns an object that can be iterated over. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

In short, it loops over the elements of an iterable (like a list), as well as an index number, combined in a tuple:

```
for item in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]):
    print item
```

prints

```
(0, "a")
(1, "b")
(2, "c")
```

It's helpful if you want to loop over a sequence (or other iterable thing), and also want to have an index counter available. If you want the counter to start from some other value (usually 1), you can give that as second argument to `enumerate`.

Comment: if you add a second variable to `item` then you can remove the parenthesis :D

Comment: Pedantic: It's a function returning an iterator, not a generator. [Generators are a specific class of user-defined functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52970099/364696) (using `yield`/`yield from`, or generator expressions, which implicitly `yield`); `enumerate` isn't a generator. For all duck-typing related purposes there is no difference, but explicit type checking and the Python language docs only uses the term "generator" for one purpose, which doesn't cover `enumerate`.

Answer (score 25):

I am reading a book (*Effective Python*) by Brett Slatkin and he shows another way to iterate over a list and also know the index of the current item in the list **but** he suggests that it is better not to use it and to use `enumerate` instead. 
I know you asked what enumerate means, but when I understood the following, I also understood how `enumerate` makes iterating over a list while knowing the index of the current item easier (and more readable).

```
list_of_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in range(len(list_of_letters)):
    letter = list_of_letters[i]
    print (i, letter)
```

The output is:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

I also used to do something, even sillier before I read about the `enumerate` function.

```
i = 0
for n in list_of_letters:
    print (i, n)
    i += 1
```

It produces the same output.

But with `enumerate` I just have to write:

```
list_of_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, letter in enumerate(list_of_letters):
    print (i, letter)
```

Answer (score 23):

As other users have mentioned, `enumerate` is a generator that adds an incremental index next to each item of an iterable.

So if you have a list say `l = ["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]`, the `list(enumerate(l))` will give you something like this: `[(0, 'test_1'), (1, 'test_2'), (2, 'test_3')]`.

**Now, when this is useful?** A possible use case is when you want to iterate over items, and you want to skip a specific item that you only know its index in the list but not its value (because its value is not known at the time).

```
for index, value in enumerate(joint_values):
   if index == 3:
       continue

   # Do something with the other `value`
```

So your code reads better because you could also do a regular for loop with `range` but then to access the items you need to index them (i.e., `joint_values[i]`).

Although another user mentioned an implementation of `enumerate` using `zip`, I think a more pure (but slightly more complex) way without using `itertools` is the following:

```
def enumerate(l, start=0):
    return zip(range(start, len(l) + start), l)
```

Example:

```
l = ["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]
enumerate(l)
enumerate(l, 10)
```

Output:

> [(0, 'test_1'), (1, 'test_2'), (2, 'test_3')]
>
> [(10, 'test_1'), (11, 'test_2'), (12, 'test_3')]

As mentioned in the comments, this approach with range will not work with arbitrary iterables as the original `enumerate` function does.

Comment: The reason the other answer mentions `itertools` is that your `range` approach only works with containers. `enumerate` works with arbitrary iterables; if you want to iterate a file, `for lineno, line in enumerate(myfile):` works, but you couldn't do `range(len(myfile))` because the length isn't known until you reach EOF.

Answer (score 14):

The enumerate function works as follows:

```
doc = """I like movie. But I don't like the cast. The story is very nice"""
doc1 = doc.split('.')
for i in enumerate(doc1):
     print(i)
```

The output is

```
(0, 'I like movie')
(1, " But I don't like the cast")
(2, ' The story is very nice')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you know how to iterate over elements in some list:

```
for el in my_list:
    # do something
```

Now sometimes not only you need to iterate over the elements, but also you need the index for each iteration. One way to do it is:

```
i = 0
for el in my_list:
    # do somethings, and use value of "i" somehow
    i += 1
```

However, a nicer way is to user the function "enumerate". What enumerate does is that it receives a list, and it returns a list-like object (an iterable that you can iterate over) but each element of this new list itself contains 2 elements:  the index and the value from that original input list:
So if you have

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then the command
`enumerate(arr)`
returns something like:

```
[(0,'a'), (1,'b'), (2,'c')]
```

Now If you iterate over a list (or an iterable) where each element itself has 2 sub-elements, you can capture both of those sub-elements in the `for` loop like below:

```
for index, value in enumerate(arr):
    print(index,value)
```

which would print out the sub-elements of the output of enumerate.

And in general you can basically "unpack" multiple items from list into multiple variables like below:

```
idx,value = (2,'c')
print(idx)
print(value)
```

which would print

```
2
c
```

This is the kind of assignment happening in each iteration of that loop with `enumerate(arr)` as iterable.

Answer (score 0):

the enumerate function calculates an elements index and the elements value at the same time. i believe the following code will help explain what is going on.

```
for i,item in enumerate(initial_config):
     print(f'index{i} value{item}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The enumerate function is used to keep count of iterations. It takes in two parameters: an iterable and a start index as seen here: `enumerate(iterable, start=1)`

If no start index is specified, it starts at 0 by default. It returns the index and the corresponding element in the iterable. Consider the following example:

```py
for i, j in enumerate(range(5)):
    print(i,'=',j)
```

The output will be:

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 4
```