# Evaluate multiple complex conditional statements in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to perform conditional logic with this dataframe.

```
In[5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'WINNER': [2, 2, 0], 'PREDICTED': [2, 1, 0], 'HOME': [5.25, 2.2, 1.25], 'DRAW': [4.5, 3.2, 5], 'AWAY': [1.53, 3.4, 8]})
In[6]: df
Out[6]: 
   AWAY  DRAW  HOME  PREDICTED  WINNER
0  1.53   4.5  5.25          2       2
1  3.40   3.2  2.20          1       2
2  8.00   5.0  1.25          0       0
```

Using the following rules, I want to calculate a new `profit` column.

```
In[14]: df.loc[(df["WINNER"] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 0), "PROFIT"] = df['HOME'] * 10
In[16]: df.loc[(df["WINNER"] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 1), "PROFIT"] = df['DRAW'] * 10
In[17]: df.loc[(df["WINNER"] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 2), "PROFIT"] = df['AWAY'] * 10
```

I almost got the correct result:

```
   AWAY  DRAW  HOME  PREDICTED  WINNER  PROFIT
0  1.53   4.5  5.25          2       2    15.3
1  3.40   3.2  2.20          1       2     NaN
2  8.00   5.0  1.25          0       0    12.5
```

**Is it possible to simplify the code in line #14-17?**

**How can I get table below such that NaN => -10?**

```
AWAY  DRAW  HOME  PREDICTED  WINNER  PROFIT
0  1.53   4.5  5.25          2       2    15.3
1  3.40   3.2  2.20          1       2     -10
2  8.00   5.0  1.25          0       0    12.5
```

EDIT: I like proposed by `imp9` solution with little modifications

```
categories = ['HOME', 'DRAW', 'AWAY']
df['PROFIT'] = -10
for count, col in enumerate(categories):
   df.loc[df.query('WINNER == PREDICTED == @count').index, "PROFIT"] += df[col] * 10
```

Comment: Please check your modification, you are now setting everything to -10, and then adding your values. Your output dataframe is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
categories = ['HOME', 'DRAW', 'AWAY']
for count, col in enumerate(categories):
    df.loc[df.query('WINNER == PREDICTED == @count').index, "PROFIT"] = df[col] * 10
df.fillna({'PROFIT': -10}, inplace = True)
```

- Use a for loop with [enumerate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171593/1435522) to incrementally fill in the profit column.
- Use [`df.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to further simplify writing the conditional logic. The query must be passed as a string and variables should be preceded with `@`.
- [`df.fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna) lets you replace all the NaN values in the dataframe.

EDIT: used a dictionary so only Nan in `PROFIT` column is filled.

Comment: categories = ['HOME', 'DRAW', 'AWAY']
  df['PROFIT'] = -10
  for count, col in enumerate(categories):
      df.loc[df.query('WINNER == PREDICTED == @count').index, "PROFIT"] += df[col] * 10

Comment: I updated the description, because couldn't beauty code in comments. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I have made edit so not all Nan will be filled. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. There is no compulsion.

Comment: `df.loc[df.query('WINNER == PREDICTED == @count').index, "PROFIT"]` - will you not catch the error due absence of `PROFIT`-column?

Comment: Pandas will create a column for `PROFIT`. When you are trying to assign a value to a column that doesn't exist, pandas will create that column.

Answer (score 1):

Consider numpy's [np.where()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to reflect a nested if/then/else. The false argument would be -10:

```
df["PROFIT"] = np.where((df["WINNER"] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 0), 
                         df['HOME'] * 10,
                 np.where((df["WINNER"] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 1), 
                          df['DRAW'] * 10,
                   np.where((df["WINNER"] == df["PREDICTED"]) & (df["PREDICTED"] == 2), 
                             df['AWAY'] * 10, -10)))
```