# Working of Enumerate in Python

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I'm new to Python and I'm currently solving questions to improve my coding skills. I came across the question where I to find the maximum value in a `List` and it's corresponding value in an other `List` with the same `index` number of the maximum value.

for example:
I have two `Lists` with values  `L1 = [9, 12, 9 ,6]` and `L2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]`
I have to find the maximum value in the `List L1` and the index of the maximum value should be used in `List L2` to find it's corresponding value.

```
Max value in List L1 - 12
Index of the max value - 1
print L2[1] -> 3
```

So to achieve the above logic, I have re-searched a way and obtained it. But I'm not able to understand how the logic is working.

```
import operator   
index, value = max(enumerate(l1), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print value, 
print l2[index]
```

OUTPUT: `12 3`

To understand how the above function is working, I tried to print each section separately but still not able to understand how the logic is working.

```
print l1 - [9, 12, 9 , 6]
print l2 - [2, 3, 4, 5]
print list(enumerate(l1)) - [<0, 9>, <1, 12>, <2, 9>, <3, 6>]
print list(enumerate(l2)) - [<0, 2>, <1, 3>, <2, 4>, <3, 5>]
print max(enumerate(l1)) - <3, 6>
print max(enumerate(l2)) - <3, 5>
```

Please help me in understanding how the `enumerate` function and `key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]`is working in the above logic. Thanks in advance. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you Google the pieces? [`enumerate`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+enumerate), [`operator.itemgetter`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+itemgetter), and [`key`](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+max+key)? What, specifically, do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) creates a generator function that effectively turns a list of values into a list of tuples.

```
L1 = [9, 12, 9, 6]
```

becomes

```
[(0, 9), (1, 12), (2, 9), (3, 6)]
```

The [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function finds the maximum value in that list.  If no other arguments were provided to `max`, it would compare the `tuples` to each other and this item would be the max - `(3, 6)`.  But that's not what we want.  We don't want it to use the `enumerate` number in the comparison.

`max` accepts a `key` argument, which should be a function that takes one argument, which will be the value from the list, and should return a value that will be used to sort the list and choose a maximum.  In this case, we want to sort the list based on the second number in each tuple (i.e the `6` in `(3, 6)`).

[`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is a function that returns a function, which will return an indexed item of the thing it's called on.  For example:

```
L1 = [3, 4, 6, 2]
f = operator.itemgetter(0)
f(L1)
# 3

f = operator.itemgetter(2)
f(L1)
# 6
```

In this case, it uses `operator.itemgetter(1)`, which is going to return the `6` in `(3, 6)`

So the result we get from `max(enumerate(l1), key=operator.itemgetter(1))` is a `tuple` with the index of the max value and the max value in `L1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I couldn't understand how `operator.itemgetter(1)` is working and what value should be given in the brackets, how is 1 in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate()` simply produces tuples with the original value plus an index, in the order `(index, item)`, for each item in the input iterable. See *[What does enumerate mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)*

`max()` picks out the maximum value from a sequence, given a key. The default key is to use the value itself, but with `operator.itemgetter(1)`, you are telling `max()` to only pay attention to the second value of each input item.

You could easily play with this to see that `max()` always returns an original value from the list, but alters what value is returned when using a `key` function. You can use any function, including one created with a `lambda`:

```
>>> L1 = [9, 12, 9, 6]
>>> max(L1)  # straight up, biggest value in the list
12
>>> max(L1, key=lambda v: len(str(v)))  # value with the most digits, 12 has two digits
12
>>> max(L1, key=lambda v: abs(v - 10))  # value furthest from 10; 6 is the furthest
6
```

When you call `operator.itemgetter()` with at least one argument, it'll produce an object that *when called with a sequence*, will use the argument(s) as indices for that sequence. `operator.itemgetter(1)` creates an object that always picks the *second* element (Python starts counting from `0`), `operator.itemgetter(2)` would return the 3rd element each time you call it:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> ig2 = itemgetter(2)
>>> ig2
operator.itemgetter(2)
>>> ig2(L1)  # the 3rd element in L1 is 9
9
```

Given that `enumerate()` puts the original value in the second position of each tuple it produces, `max()` picking the maximum value from the sequence of tuples based on the value from the original input list. It'll keep the tuples produced by `enumerate()` intact however.

If you omitted the `key`, you'd get the biggest 'tuple'; tuples are compared by the first element contained that is different. So `(1, 2)` is bigger than `(1, 0)` because the second element, `2` is bigger than `0`. But `(2, 1)` is bigger than `(1, 1)` because the first element differs and `2` is the larger one. Since `enumerate()` adds increasing indices (starting at `0`) that means `max()` without a `key` will always pick the *last* element:

```
>>> max(enumerate(l1))  # last element is (3, 6)
(3, 6)
```

That element was picked because `3` is the highest index.

Note that using `enumerate()` is overkill here. You could just use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up `L1` and `L2` instead:

```
l1max, corresponding_l2 = max(zip(L1, L2))
```

`zip()` pairs up the elements of `L1` and `L2`, producing tuples with `(9, 2)`, `(12, 3)`, etc. `max()` picks the biggest tuple from that sequence, looking first at the first element (taken from `L1`).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I'll research ok `zip` as well. thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From the help:

> Help on built-in function max in module builtins:
>
> max(...)
>       max(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
>       max(arg1, arg2, *args, *[, key=func]) -> value
>
> ```
> With a single iterable argument, return its biggest item. The
> default keyword-only argument specifies an object to return if
> the provided iterable is empty.
> With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
> ```

And the

> Help on class itemgetter in module operator:
>
> class itemgetter(builtins.object)  |  itemgetter(item, ...) -->
>   itemgetter object  |    |  Return a callable object that fetches the
>   given item(s) from its operand.  |  After f = itemgetter(2), the call
>   f(r) returns r[2].  |  After g = itemgetter(2, 5, 3), the call g(r)
>   returns (r[2], r[5], r[3])

So, itemgetter does what its name says: it gets the specified item(s) from
the elements of a list. 
In this case, the second elements (those with index 1).
This is what you do:

You call max on the output generated by enumerate:

```
[<0, 9>, <1, 12>, <2, 9>, <3, 6>]
```

and tell it to determine the maximum based on the key defined by:

```
key=operator.itemgetter(1)),
```

that is, the second value of each element in the list. Then max returns
the element it found, which is of the form (index, value).

Answer (score -3):

@Dev: The Enumerate function just prints the list and its index value and key is something you want to operate with respect to data structure , Please find the code below

```
index, value = min(enumerate(l1), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print value
6
print index
3
index, value = max(enumerate(l1), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print index
1
print value
12
sorted(enumerate(l1), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
[(3, 6), (0, 9), (2, 9), (1, 12)]
sorted(enumerate(l1), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
[(0, 9), (1, 12), (2, 9), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: I am trying to explain enumerate and key operator, with the above example