# What Does Enumerate Do in This Context [Python]

Tags: python-3.x

I know that there is another answer to this but that's for complex users. I'm a basic python user who started a couple of days ago. So I need a simple answer

Im trying to understand this line of code. Mostly the enumerate part. Could someone please what enumerate does.

```
f = open("solutions.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does enumerate mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) before asking this question?

Comment: @MattBall Yes I have but I need a simple explanation in context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enumerate` is used to generate a line index, the `i` variable, together with the `line` string, which is the i-th line in the text file. Getting an index from an iterable is such a common idiom on any `iterable` that `enumerate` provides an elegant way to do this. You could, of course, just initialize an integer counter `i` and increment it after each line is read, but enumerate does that for you. The main advantage is code readability: the `i` variable initialization and increment statements would be book-keeping code that is not strictly necessary to show the intent of what that loop is trying to do. Python excels at revealing the business-logic of code being concise and to the point.
You can look at Raymond Hettinger's presentation to learn more about idiomatic python from these excellent [notes](https://gist.github.com/JeffPaine/6213790).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately I didn't understand most of it. As I said I'm a beginner & still don't know much about python. Can you put it in any simpler terms?

Comment: `f = open("solutions.txt", "r")` opens the file and assigns to f, then the `f.readlines()` reads all the lines in the files and puts them in a list, assigned to the `searchlines` variable. A list in Python is an `iterable` object. The following for-loop (which in other languages is called foreach) iterates through each line in the list. Enumerate gives you something more: the index i which correspond to the index of the line in the list (and thus also the line number, although starting at 0). You should try that code by adding: print('{0}: {1}'.format(i+1, line)) in the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much. & I don't think i'd change it now as i've finally git it to work