# Python : The second for loop is not running

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
scores = []
surfers = []
results_f = open("results.txt")

for each_line in results_f:
    (name,score) = each_line.split()
    scores.append(float(score))

for line in results_f:                      
    (name,score) = line.split()
    surfers.append(name)

results_f.close()
scores.sort(reverse = True)  
print("The high scores are : ")
print("1 - "+str(scores[0]))
print("2 - "+str(scores[1]))
print("3 - "+str(scores[2]))

print(surfers[0])
```

Just an experimental program. But the second for loop doesn't seem to run. If I switch the positions of the for loops; again the loop in the second position wouldn't run. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files are not lists. You can't loop over them without rewinding the file object, as the file position doesn't reset to the start when you finished reading.

You could add `results_f.seek(0)` between the loops:

```
for each_line in results_f:
    (name,score) = each_line.split()
    scores.append(float(score))

results_f.seek(0)

for line in results_f:                      
    (name,score) = line.split()
    surfers.append(name)
```

but you'd be *much* better off by not looping twice. You already have the `name` information in the first loop. Just loop *once*:

```
for each_line in results_f:
    (name,score) = each_line.split()
    scores.append(float(score))
    surfers.append(name)
```

Your code only sorts the `scores` list; the `surfers` list will not follow suit. If you need to sort names and scores together, put your names and scores together in a list; if you put the score first you don't even need to tell `sort` anything special:

```
surfer_scores = []

for each_line in results_f:
    name, score = each_line.split()
    surfer_scores.append((float(score), name))

surfer_scores.sort(reverse=True)  
print("The high scores are : ")
for i, (score, name) in enumerate(surfer_scores[:3], 1):
    print("{} - {}: {}".format(i, name, score)
```

Comment: Thanks, just was wondering about the second for loop not working for which you already answered.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info, very helpful.

Comment: Still surprised. How could two data items be put in a single spot in a list?

Comment: @Vasanth: The magic of nested structures! There is one object in that spot, a tuple. The tuples, in turn, each contain two elements (a score and a name).

Comment: Thanks again. Learnt some. @Martijn Pieters

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain the following piece of your code,   enumerate(surfer_scores[:3], 1):

Comment: @Vasanth: see [What does enumerate mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171593), the `surfer_scores[:3]` expression takes the first 3 elements (so the 3 highest scores), and `enumerate()` adds a number to each element, starting at 1 (the second argument to `enumerate()`). So the loop gives you 3 numbered score - name pairs.