# Python item count in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, count

I was experimenting with for loops and lists in Python earlier today, and I'm a bit stuck on this one thing that's probably very simple... Here's my code:

```
animals = ["hamster","cat","monkey","giraffe","dog"]

print("There are",len(animals),"animals in the list")
print("The animals are:",animals)

s1 = str(input("Input a new animal: "))
s2 = str(input("Input a new animal: "))
s3 = str(input("Input a new animal: "))

animals.append(s1)
animals.append(s2)
animals.append(s3)

print("The list now looks like this:",animals)

animals.sort()
print("This is the list in alphabetical order:")
for item in animals:
    count = count + 1

    print("Animal number",count,"in the list is",item)
```

The count variable doesn't work for whatever reason, I've tried to search for this problem but can't find anything. It says it's not defined, but if I put a normal number or a string it works perfectly fine. (I am also sick at the moment so I can't think properly, so this might be really simple and I just didn't catch it) Would I have to make a new for loop? Because when I did this:

```
for item in animal:
    for i in range(1,8):
        print("Animal number",i,"in the list is",item)
```

It just spits out each item in the list with the numbers 1-7, which is... better, but not what I want.

Comment: You forgot to define `count`. Right before for loop add `count = 0`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define count first like:

```
count = 0
```

Another better way to achieve what you want is just:

```
for count, item in enumerate(animals):
    print("Animal number", count + 1, "in the list is", item)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize `count` before the loop.
Otherwise Python does not know what `count` is, so it cannot evaluate `count + 1`.

You should do something like

```
...
count = 0
for item in animals:
    count = count + 1
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to increment a value you never set:

```
for item in animals:
    count = count + 1
```

Python complains about `count` because the first time you use it in `count + 1`, `count` has never been set!

Set it to `0` before the loop:

```
count = 0
for item in animals:
    count = count + 1
    print("Animal number",count,"in the list is",item)
```

Now the first time the `count + 1` expression is executed, `count` exists and `count` can be updated with the `0 + 1` result.

As a more Pythonic alternative, you can use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to include a counter in the loop itself:

```
for count, item in enumerate(animals):
    print("Animal number",count,"in the list is",item)
```

See [What does enumerate mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)