# Combining two loops in Python

Tags: python-2.7

May be its an absurd question but I have this code:

```
from itertools import product

variable_ = 'variable_'
for i,oid, val in product(xrange(0,7), varBinds):
    variable_ += `i`
    print('%s = %s' % (variable_,val.prettyPrint()))
```

I get the error `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`.I don't want to use oid for now but may be later in the same loop I'll require it. I searched for the error and possible solutions but none worked.

All i want to do is `for i in range(0,7) && for oid, val in varBinds`, and get expected data as

```
variable_0=<some value in varBinds>
variable_1=<some other value in varBinds>
.
.
variable_6=<last value in varBinds>
```

how can i do that?

UPDATE:

This is what i did:

```
for i, (oid, val) in enumerate(varBinds):
variable_ += `i`
    print('%s = %s' % (variable_,val.prettyPrint()))
    variable_="variable_"
```

Worked Perfectly. 
Thanks @RemcoGerlich for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that the two latter values are in a tuple themselves:

```
for i, (oid, val) in product(xrange(0,7), varBinds):
```

Edit: from your example, you don't want `product` at all, but `enumerate`:

```
for i, (oid, val) in enumerate(varBinds):
```

See [What does enumerate mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean) .

Or possibly `itertools.izip` (an iterator version of `zip`), if the `xrange` was just an example:

```
from itertools import izip

for i, (old, val) in izip(xrange(0, 7), varBinds):
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @RemcoGerlich ! I tried this. Worked some what like i want. But I am not getting my perfect output.. May be I am horrible at loop concepts lol.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I could at least get this result
`variable_0 = <some value in varBinds>`
 `variable_01 = <some other value in varBinds>`

`......variable_0123456 = <last value in varBinds>
`

Now will check what is my fault.. Thanks again!! :)