# Print number of the rows Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the number of the row in 2d array (list of the list) like:

A B C D E F

1: - - - - - -

2: - - - - - -

I need to print only the number of rows 1:

can someone pls guide me

```
def printChart(list):
    print('\n  A  B  C  D  E  F')
    for i in list:
        for e in i:
            print(' ', e, end='')
        print()
    print()
```

Comment: You should add example input an example output.

Comment: [enumerate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)

Comment: my bad. will add

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, you want to add a number to the line.

```
def printChart(abc):
    print('\n  A  B  C  D  E  F')
    for x,i in enumerate(abc):
        print(x, ' ', i)

alpha = ["A", "B" , "C" ,"D", "E", "F"]
printChart(alpha)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   F
```