# How to extract a word from the line which is next to particular keyword

Tags: python

I want to extract a word which is next to the keyword in the line.
Note: The keyword exists twice in the line and I want to print both words next to the keyword.

**Example:**

```
This is my first Python language and I like this language to the most.
```

Desired Output:(need words next to `language` in below format)

```
and    
to
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried extracting a word based on index value, but I was unable to extract using keyword.                                                                                                   with open("one.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
      word_list = line.split(' 
      print word_list[6]
      print word_list[11]

Comment: post your tried code here so we can help you better.

Comment: with open("acl.txt", "r") as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
      word_list = line.split('  ')
      print word_list[6]
      print word_list[11]

Comment: post it in the question body not in comments

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` with zero-width positive lookbehind (`(?<=language )`) to match `language` before, then getting the desired substrings with `\w+` and `print`-ing with `sep='\n'` to get desired output format:

```
In [33]: s = 'This is my first Python language and I like this language to the most.'

In [34]: print(*re.findall(r'(?<=language )\w+', s), sep='\n')
and   
to
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But it says invalid syntax for me when I execute

Comment: @SaiKiran What command did you run exactly? Add that to your question along with your `python` version.

Comment: The same one which you gave me above.
s = 'This is my first Python language and I like this language to the most.'
print (*re.findall(r'(?<=language )\w+', s), sep='\n')

Comment: @SaiKiran If you're on Python 2: `print '\n'.join(re.findall(r'(?<=language )\w+', s))`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = 'This is my first Python language and I like this language to the most.'


for i, word in enumerate(data.split()):
    if word == 'language':
        print(data.split()[i + 1])
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, this is simple and I could get output as desired.

Comment: Thanks. Have a good day too... Sorry for late question: what does function        ' enumerate ' do ?

Comment: I think this is what the code above is doing. Basically the data.split() is separating the string (text) by the spaces. If you print the data.split() you actually get a python list with separate entries for all the words. What enumerate does is it turns that list into an enumerate object. It is really a list containing tuples, looking like (counter, value). Here it is in a simpler form:  data.split() = ['This', 'is', 'my','first']    enumerate(data.split()) = [('0','This'), ('1','is'), ('2','my'),('3','first')]

Comment: Or here is a link to an answer which has way better explaining then me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171593/8625593

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "hola esto es una prueba donde esto busca la siguiente linea de esto"
brk = "esto"
for i, texto in enumerate(text.split(brk)):
  if i > 0:
    print( texto.split()[0] if len(texto.split()) > 0 else '')
```

And now you just have to change the text and the break work