# Python: Looping and nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, hash

I have 3 tuples:

```
o = (0, 1)
n = ((1, 2), (1,))
c = ((30, 70), (20,))
```

that I want to put in a nested dictionary. The desired output is:

```
{'0':{'1':30, '2':70}, '1':{'1':20}}
```

I tried the following:

```
for x in enumerate(o):
    graph[str(o[x])] = {}
    for y in enumerate(n):
        for z in enumerate(y):
            graph[str(o[x])][n[x][z]] = c[x][z]
```

Which does not work, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Note that `(1)` and `(20)` are not tuples.

Comment: `{ko: {kn:vc for kn, vc in zip(N, C)} for ko, N, C in zip(o, n, c)}` would work if `(1)` and `(20)` were made into tuples. i.e. changed to `(1,)` and `(20,)` respectively.

Comment: Sorry (1) and (20) were supposed to be tuples (1,) and (20,).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is arising from the fact that `(1)` and `(20)` are not tuples (as pointed out by [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%c3%a4) in the comments). Since they are actually of type `int`, you can not iterate over them or use `[]` to index.

First a note about `enumerate()`, which you were using incorrectly. This function returns a tuple of `(index, value)`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean).

If changing the source data is not an option, you can modify your code a little to get the desired result. Loop over the tuples as before, but use `isinstance` to check if the element is an `int`.

```
graph = {}
for i, x in enumerate(o):
    graph[x] = {}
    if isinstance(n[i], int):
        graph[x][n[i]] = c[i]
    else:
        for j in range(len(n[i])):
            graph[x][n[i][j]] = c[i][j]
print graph
#{0: {1: 30, 2: 70}, 1: {1: 20}}
```

This `else` block of this code can be simplified further, using [`zip()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/5858851):

```
graph = {}
for i, x in enumerate(o):
    graph[x] = {}
    if isinstance(n[i], int):
        graph[x][n[i]] = c[i]
    else:
        for y, z in zip(n[i], c[i]):
            graph[x][y] = z
print graph
#{0: {1: 30, 2: 70}, 1: {1: 20}}
```

However, the better solution is to change the source data `n` and `c` to contain only tuples:

```
def make_tuple(x):
    return x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x, )

new_n = map(make_tuple, n)
new_c = map(make_tuple, c)
```

Then the code above no longer needs the `isinstance()` check, and can be simplified to:

```
graph = {}
for i, x in enumerate(o):
    graph[x] = {}
    for y, z in zip(new_n[i], new_c[i]):
        graph[x][y] = z
print graph
#{0: {1: 30, 2: 70}, 1: {1: 20}}
```

We can simplify further into:

```
graph = {}
for ko, N, C in zip(o, new_n, new_c):
    graph[ko] = {}
    for kn, vc in zip(N, C):
        graph[ko][kn] = vc
print graph
#{0: {1: 30, 2: 70}, 1: {1: 20}}
```

Or if to the compact one liner (direct translation of the code block above to dict comprehension):

```
graph = {ko: {kn:vc for kn, vc in zip(N, C)} for ko, N, C in zip(o, new_n, new_c)}
print graph
#{0: {1: 30, 2: 70}, 1: {1: 20}}
```

Comment: @Bee, based on your latest comment I see that much of this is not applicable to your problem. Does this make sense to you or would you like further clarification?

Comment: Yes, everything is clear now, thank you so much for your help!