# How to print the progress of a list comprehension in python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

In my method i have to return a list within a list. I would like to have a list comprehension, because of the performance since the list takes about 5 minutes to create.

```
[[token.text for token in document] for document in doc_collection]
```

Is there a possibility to print out the progress, in which document the create-process currently are? Something like that:

```
[[token.text for token in document] 
  and print(progress) for progress, document in enumerate(doc_collection)]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use a loop instead of the comprehension!

Comment: @KlausD. For sure this would work, but is there no possibility to add it in the comprehension? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @KlausD. a `for` loop is way slower than `list comprehension` when creating lists

Comment: @Chris_Rands Nice find. But I think this question is the better one (shorter and clearer, and no `pandas` usage), so it might be better to close the older question as a dupe of this one. We just need a "Don't do that; use a for loop instead" answer, then we're all set.

Comment: @Aran-Fey too late... But I can reopen and do this. done

Comment: @Aran-Fey "But I think this question is the better one " okay so why it has only one upvote (which isn't yours?)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I see your point, but I answered the other question with both the `print() or` and side function ideas and a bit more explanation than given in these answers, but I guess I'm biased *sigh*

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre better doesn't mean good :p

Comment: @Chris_Rands you got some votes for that recently though ? :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I do think that the answers in the older question are better; I just don't like the verbosity (and the `pandas` usage) of the question. This one here is easier to understand for a wider audience. Given the circumstances, I think nobody would blame you for re-posting your answer here :)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I guess the alternative would be to improve the other question by striping it back to the essential parts

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## `tqdm`

Using the [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) package, a fast and versatile progress bar utility

```
pip install tqdm
```

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

def process(token):
    return token['text']

l1 = [{'text': k} for k in range(5000)]
l2 = [process(token) for token in tqdm(l1)]
```

```
100%|███████████████████████████████████| 5000/5000 [00:00<00:00, 2326807.94it/s]
```

## No requirement

#### 1/ Use a side function

```
def report(index):
    if index % 1000 == 0:
        print(index)

def process(token, index, report=None):
    if report:
        report(index) 
    return token['text']

l1 = [{'text': k} for k in range(5000)]

l2 = [process(token, i, report) for i, token in enumerate(l1)]
```

#### 2/ Use `and` and `or` statements

```
def process(token):
    return token['text']

l1 = [{'text': k} for k in range(5000)]
l2 = [(i % 1000 == 0 and print(i)) or process(token) for i, token in enumerate(l1)]
```

#### 3/ Use both

```
def process(token):
    return token['text']

def report(i):
    i % 1000 == 0 and print(i)

l1 = [{'text': k} for k in range(5000)]
l2 = [report(i) or process(token) for i, token in enumerate(l1)]
```

---

All 3 methods print:

```
0
1000
2000
3000
4000
```

---

**How 2 works**

- `i % 1000 == 0 and print(i)`: `and` only checks the second statement if the first one is `True` so only prints when `i % 1000 == 0`
- `or process(token)`: `or` always checks both statements,  but returns the first one which evals to `True`.

  - If `i % 1000 != 0` then the first statement is `False` and `process(token)` is added to the list.
  - Else, then the first statement is `None` (because `print` returns `None`) and likewise, the `or` statement adds `process(token)` to the list

**How 3 works**

Similarly as 2, because `report(i)` does not `return` anything, it evals to `None` and `or` adds `process(token)` to the list

Comment: instead of using a `global i`, I would go with `enumerate` and pass the `index` to the `function`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis and factor out the reporting part using a callback, too (code edited to fix both points).

Comment: This is both slower and less readable than a `for` loop. In my (admittedly very limited) tests, Alex's solution takes 10 seconds, a `for` loop takes 13, and this one takes 17.

Comment: @Aran-Fey The functionality is different though; one cannot compare them directly.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Huh? What's different? The result is the same, as far as I can tell...

Comment: You can turn the reporting on and off and there is an `if` statement for the `print`s. Alex's answer just `print`s everything. Not sure how your `for` loop looks like.

Comment: This is the standard method. But you really, really should use `if index % 1000 == 0 and index > 0:` in the test - it is much cleaner. :)

Comment: @ted, why do you pass `tok` to `report`? The function does nothing with this argument, so imo it can be omitted.

Comment: This is true, it's more of a display for how it could be used

Answer (score 4):

```
doc_collection = [[1, 2],
                  [3, 4],
                  [5, 6]]

result = [print(progress) or
          [str(token) for token in document]
          for progress, document in enumerate(doc_collection)]

print(result)  # [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

I don't consider this good or readable code, but the idea is fun.

It works because `print` always returns `None` so `print(progress) or x` will always be `x` (by the definition of `or`).

Comment: This should NOT be the accepted answer  - as far as I'm concerned, such a code will not pass a code review. Ted's solution is the correct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

def foo(i):
    sleep(0.01)
    return i

[foo(i) for i in tqdm(range(1000))]
```

For Jupyter notebook:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

Comment: Consider using `from tqdm import trange` Then `[foo(i) for i in trange(1000))]`. It is a shortcut for `tqdm(range(N))`

Answer (score 2):

```
def show_progress(it, milestones=1):
    for i, x in enumerate(it):
        yield x
        processed = i + 1
        if processed % milestones == 0:
            print('Processed %s elements' % processed)
```

Simply apply this function to anything you're iterating over. It doesn't matter if you use a loop or list comprehension and it's easy to use anywhere with almost no code changes. For example:

```
doc_collection = [[1, 2],
                  [3, 4],
                  [5, 6]]

result = [[str(token) for token in document]
          for document in show_progress(doc_collection)]

print(result)  # [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
```

If you only wanted to show progress for every 100 documents, write:

```
show_progress(doc_collection, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation.

`pip install progressbar2`

```
from progressbar import progressbar
new_list = [your_function(list_item) for list_item in progressbar(old_list)]`
```

You will see a progress bar while running the code block above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the need to make @ted's answer (imo) more readable and to add some explanations.

**Tidied up solution:**

```
# Function to print the index, if the index is evenly divisable by 1000:
def report(index):
    if index % 1000 == 0:
        print(index)

# The function the user wants to apply on the list elements
def process(x, index, report):
     report(index) # Call of the reporting function
     return 'something ' + x # ! Just an example, replace with your desired application

# !Just an example, replace with your list to iterate over
mylist = ['number ' + str(k) for k in range(5000)]

# Running a list comprehension
[process(x, index, report) for index, x in enumerate(mylist)]
```

**Explanation:** of `enumerate(mylist)`: using the function `enumerate` it is possible to have indices in addition to the elements of an iterable object (cf. [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22171558/6256241)). For example

```
[(index, x) for index, x in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"])] #returns
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

**Note:** `index` and `x` are no reserved names, just names I found convenient - `[(foo, bar) for foo, bar in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"])]` yields the same result.