# Turn multiple body lines into list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that I want to write as list comprehension:

```
word = "in_str"
listc=[]
for i in range(len(list(word))):
    x = []
    x.append(i+1)
    x.append(list(word)[i])
    listc.append(x)
print(listc, end="\n")
```

How do I treat the multiple lines in the body?
Basically, I want to transform my `"in_str"` into the following:

```
[[1, 'i'], [2, 'n'], [3, '_'], [4, 's'], [5, 't'], [6, 'r']]
```

Comment: `list(enumerate(word, 1))` or `[list(t) for t in enumerate(word, 1)]` for a list of lists

Comment: You don't need to use multiple lines at all; `listc.append([i + 1, word[i]])` can replace your whole loop body; lists don't have to start empty.

Comment: `[*map(list, enumerate(word, 1))]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a varitey options with this one, and more that arent listed

```
l = [[idx, item] for idx, item in enumerate(word, 1)]

l = list(map(list, enumerate(word, 1)))

l = list(map(list, zip(range(1, len(word)+1), word)))

l = []
for idx, item in enumerate(word, 1):
    l.append([idx, item])

# [[1, 'i'], [2, 'n'], [3, '_'], [4, 's'], [5, 't'], [6, 'r']]
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree with your stance on the enumerate zip combo and took that down, I left one zip example just based on the OP questioning about the zip procedures for this, thank your for help refining this answer

Comment: You could take a look at [my answer on `enumerate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean/22171593#22171593); `range()` is much more verbose an object here than is needed to re-create `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I treat the multiple lines in the body

By simplifying the expression down; you don't need multiple statements to build the nested list:

```
[i + 1, list(word)[i]]
```

gives you the same result as declaring `x = []` and appending two the results of two expressions.

That would make the list comprehension

```
[
    [i + 1, list(word)[i]]
    for i in range(len(list(word)))
]
```

Next, you don't need to call `list(word)` to get the length of a string or to address individual characters. Strings are already sequences, so `len(word)` and `word[i]` also work:

```
[
    [i + 1, word[i]]
    for i in range(len(word))
]
```

Next, if you used the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), you can generate both a running index to replace the `range()` loop, *and* get access to the individual characters of `word` without having to index; you can start the running index at `1` with a second argument to `enumerate()` (the default is to start at `0`):

```
[[i, char] for i, char in enumerate(word, 1)]
```

If you don't *have* to have a *list* for each pair, just use `enumerate(word, 1)` directly in loops and get tuples:

```
list(enumerate(word, 1))
```

Demo:

```
>>> word = "in_str"
>>> list(enumerate(word, 1))
[(1, 'i'), (2, 'n'), (3, '_'), (4, 's'), (5, 't'), (6, 'r')]
>>> [[i, char] for i, char in enumerate(word, 1)]
[[1, 'i'], [2, 'n'], [3, '_'], [4, 's'], [5, 't'], [6, 'r']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this line:

```
[(i + 1, l) for i, l in enumerate(word)]
```

Or with lists:

```
[[i + 1, l] for i, l in enumerate(word)]
```

or a version from the comments (by @tobias_k):

```
list(enumerate(word, start=1))
```

Comment: You can use `enumerate(word, start=1)`

Answer (score 2):

I would do as such;

`new_list = [list(x) for x in enumerate(word)]`

this gives;

`[[0, 'i'], [1, 'n'], [2, '_'], [3, 's'], [4, 't'], [5, 'r']]`

EDIT: I see @Chris_Rands beat me to the punch, put it as an answer good sir!

Comment: Thanks! I changed to `list(x+1)` so the index starts at 1

Comment: @rororo `list(x+1)` does not work, `x` is a tuple, but you can use the `start=1` parameter of `enumerate`

Comment: can I also use `zip()` for this task?

Comment: @rororo You _could_ use `zip` and a `range`, but why bother? `enumerate` already does that for you.

Comment: @rororo: why complicate matters with `zip()`? `enumerate(word, start)` is essentially `zip(itertools.count(start), word)`, but using the latter only causes confusion for future readers of the code, including whomever chose to use the obscure version over the standard library function.