# iterate through a list by skipping every 5th element

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am working a Rubik's cube assignment and I need help to complete one of the steps.
I need to iterate through a list by comparing the elements and skipping every 5th element.
so far I was able to find this:

```
newList =['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26']
for elem in newList[ : : 5]:
    print elem
```

using this, I only get every 5th element to be printed, which is the opposite of what I want.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[newList[each] for each in range(len(newList)) if each % 5 != 4]
```

i am using python3 though, try if it works for you too.

as other answers suggested, using enumeration results better:

```
[each for index, each in enumerate(newList) if index % 5 != 4]
```

Comment: The 5th element means `each == 4`, which `each % 5 != 0` and will not be skipped.  You will be skipping every 6th element `5` instead.  I think you're looking for `(each + 1) % 5 != 0` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`enumerate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean) function as you're iterating, so that you know which index the element has in the list. Then you can perform your checks easily:

```
for index, elem in enumerate(newList):
    if index % 4 == 0:
        # do something
```

Comment: It still prints only every 5th element. but when I tried           if index %4 != 0:                                                                       it worked, but did not start from '0'

Comment: @Plagga That was just to demonstrate what you could do with `enumerate`. Since this is a homework assignment, I thought I'd leave it to you to figure out how you could use `index` to your advantage to get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the index of the element to skip.

```
for index, elem in enumerate(newList):
    if index != 4:    
        print elem
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: This will not excluded the 10th, 15th, 20th ... elements

Comment: Oh! I did not not notice that every 5th element. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
    array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

    count = 1

    for i in array1:
        if count % 5 != 0:
           count += 1
           print(i)
        else:
           count += 1
```

Comment: this is helpful too, Thanks!