# How do you iterate over a list of class objects in Python

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I'm attempting to iterate over a list of class objects/module objects to check collision and this error is thrown:

```
  File "C:/Users/travi/PycharmProjects/game/main.py", line 81, in <module>
if collision.collision1.is_collision(player.player1.vel, player.player1.x1, player.player1.x2, player.player1.y1, player.player1.y2, environmentVector[i].x1, environmentVector[i].x2, environmentVector[i].y1, environmentVector[i].y2):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not environment
```

heres the code (from main.py)

```
    for i in environmentVector:
        if collision.collision1.is_collision(player.player1.vel, player.player1.x1, player.player1.x2, player.player1.y1, player.player1.y2, environmentVector[i].x1, environmentVector[i].x2, environmentVector[i].y1, environmentVector[i].y2):
            print("collision")
```

environment.py:

```
import pygame

class environment():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x1 = x - 16
        self.x2 = x + 16
        self.y1 = y - 16
        self.y2 = y + 16
```

collision.py:

```
import pygame
import player
import enemy
import environment

class collision():
    def __init__(self):
        self.collision = False

    def is_collision(self, moveSpeed, x1, x2, y1, y2, X1, X2, Y1, Y2):
        if (((x2 + moveSpeed >= X1) and (x2 <= X2)) and (((y2 >= Y1) and (y2 <= Y2)) or ((y1 <= Y2) and (y1 >= Y1)))) or (((x1 - moveSpeed <= X2) and (x1 >= X1)) and (((y2 >= Y1) and (y2 <= Y2)) or ((y1 <= Y2) and (y1 >= Y1)))):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: environmentVector[i].x1 -> i.x1

Comment: Python loops are for-each loops. In every iteration, `i` is the environment object itself, not a counter.

Comment: That’s a lot of redundant `(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `for` loops are "for-each" type loops, unlike the traditional `for` loops in C and some other languages. In every iteration, loop variable (`i` in your case) is the next element in the container.
Assuming `vec` is an `std::vector<int>` type, this in C++:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i){
    std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Is roughly the equivalent of this in Python (`lst` is assumed to be a `list` object):

```
for i in lst:
    print(i)
```

As you can see `i` is the element itself, not its index.

Having said that, this is how your for loop could be fixed:

```
for i in environmentVector:
    if collision.collision1.is_collision(player.player1.vel, player.player1.x1, player.player1.x2, player.player1.y1, player.player1.y2, i.x1, i.x2, i.y1, i.y2):
        print("collision")
```

Notice that I replaced `environmentVector[i]`s with just `i`s.

If you absolutely need indexes, you may use [enumerate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171593/10147399):
(`lst` is again assumed to be `list` object):

```
for indx, obj in enumerate(lst):
    print(indx, obj)
```

Here, in every iteration, you'll get the index assigned to `indx` and the object itself assigned to `obj`