# How the for and enumerate function work together, in this nested loop over the contents of a 2D array?

Tags: python

I somehow understand how enumeration works, and I know how for loops work. I just mostly don't understand the tile and tiles and how that works out

```
for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map_data):
    for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
        if tile == "1":
        Wall(self. col, row)
```

So this is supposed to take a `map.txt` file with a bunch of `1`'s representing walls and `0`'s representing blank space. This code runs through all of those areas and places what is supposed to be there accordingly, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajR4BZBKTr4&list=PLsk-HSGFjnaH5yghzu7PcOzm9NhsW0Urw&index=38) video.

Comment: `print( list( enumerate(self.map_data) ))` and you will see what you have.

Comment: map has rows and columns. First `for` gets single row from map with its row's number, second `for` gets single cell from row with its `column's number.

Comment: I understand it is printing out its index number with a whole row. How is it finding the 1's and the .'s and seperating them?

Comment: So apparently my mind seems to think row and col means something code wise.. Until I replaced them with cow and dol and it still ran. This just confused me even more.

Comment: you have second `for` loop to get single item from row

Comment: `row`, and `col` are normal variables and enumerate will assign values 0, 1,2,3,etc to them. You can call them `cow` or `dol` but it is good to have names which explain what you have in variable. In `row` you will have row's number, in `col` you will have `column's number` - you can also name it `x, y`

Comment: If you're simply asking *"How does this nested loop iterate over the contents of a 2D array?"*, then that's just equivalent to asking *"How is a 2D array laid out in Python? (as a list-of-lists)"*. As for the `enumerate` calls, they're not strictly necessary, they just give you the `row` and `col` coords as they iterate over the array. But anyway, you could have used `print()` statements to discover all that for yourself.

Comment: To the people voting to close-as-dupe, this isn't an exact duplicate of [*What does enumerate() mean?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean). This one seems to about how **nested `for`-loops with `enumerate`s can iterate over a 2D array**. Which is more about *"How is a 2D array laid out in Python? (as a list-of-lists)"*. Like the 2D version of "How does enumerate work?"*, but only when you know how 2D arrays are laid out.

Answer (score 0):

enumerate returns 2 items (per iteration) - the index (0 through n) and the elements themselves (ordered).

So this the case you give:

```
for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map_data):
    for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
        if tile == "1":
        Wall(self, col, row)
```

`map_data` is a 2D array of tiles that has rows and columns.
In the first `enumerate` you get the row number (called `row` here) and the row itself (which is a 1D array of tiles called `tiles` here). Then the second enumerate goes over this 1D array of tiles (called `tiles`) and gets the index (which is the columns) and the element itself, which is the tile (called `tile`).

You could *conceptually* rewrite this like so which might be more clear:

```
for i, map_data[i] in enumerate(map_data):
    for j, map_data[i,j] in enumerate(map_data[i]):
        tile = map_data[i,j]
        if tile == "1":
        Wall(self, col, row)
```

I don't know the context, but do notice that the `==1` relates to the element itself, *not* the index, so in this case tile is probably coded such that `1` denotes the presence of a wall.

edit: I noticed in the original code you use `self.` but I assume it's a typo, and I wrote `self,` here.

edit 2: I hope this example will help, using a list of strings, which appears to be the data you have.
let's assume you have

```
map_data = ['1111','1001','1101','1111']
```

the first loop will give `0,1,2,3` for `row` and then `'1111', 1001','1101','1111'` for `tiles`. Then the second loop will give `0,1,2,3` for `col` and `'1','1','1','1'` for `tile` on the first row (where `row` is 0 and `tiles` is `'1111'`), `0,1,2,3` and `'1','0','0','1'` for the second row (`'1001'`) etc.

Comment: I understand the first for loop now, Just cant wrap my head around the second.

Comment: The second one runs on the rows, since each row is a 1D array, you can again run a loop through it, and each element is the tile. Will an example with numbers help you?

Comment: So i have printed to the screen both the map data and tiles, Map data lists the rows with their index and every single symbol in that row. (0, "1111111111111111111"), tiles lists (1, "1") 30 times which seems to only be 1 row seperated into its elements. Is the second for loop just repeating that for every single row?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are showing, but it looks like the first row (probably the edge of the screen?) is all walls. I wouldn't choose to store the map_data this way, but it seems that it is a list of strings, and when you iterate over a string (with enumerate for example) it will go over each character (so "11111" will be treated the same as [1,1,1,1,1]). Hope this clarifies things now.

Comment: This is just incredibly confusing to me. I'm not sure if I'm just stupid but I cannot seem to understand this. I thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll try to add an example using strings, I hope it will clarify it further. I do agree that the apparent choice of storing the data of the tutorial you are following (or whichever source of this sample code) is not a very intuitive one...

Comment: He said he was going to go to a more advanced style of tilemaps later on, but I figured if I cant even imagine to understand this one then there is no reason to move on.

Comment: Just imagine you have a grid (excel spreadsheet would work fine) where each row is a row, and then you put a single character (letter or number or symbol) in a separate cell. Then you'll have rows and columns where each tile is a single character (and a single excel cell). The row should read (if you ignore the cells) what is in map_data. That's your 2D array