# Deleting indices from dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, processing-efficiency

Given is a list with unsorted indices in a list of length n. Each element of the list is only once contained. 
So the list looks like this

```
L = [13, 145, 70001, 34, ..., 533]
```

Also given is a `dictionary d` which numerical values as key. All values are element 
`{0,1}`. Like

```
d = {
        "[some data]" : 0,
        "[some data]" : 1,
        "[some data]" : 1,
        "[some data]" : 1,
        ...
        "[some data]" : 0
    }
```

There are a lot more entries in the dictionary `d` then in the list `L`.

What I want to do is deleting data from the dictionary for each position (index) from `L` if it is a `0`.

The problem that I see while proceeding it that after the each deletion the indices need to be shifted since the position within dictionary is changing. Which is quiet inefficient regarding on a large number of items in `L`. There must be an efficient way of proceeding this task.

Any ideas and suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? You gotta do it yourself first before asking for help.

Comment: A few things missing in your question: 1) An example dictionary, 2) an example list, 3) Expected output 4) Your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide example input with corresponding output? Note, *dictionaries don't have indices*

Comment: 1) look d, key value is irrelevant 2) look at L 3) expected output is a dictionary without entries on position the following positions 13, 145, 70001, 34, ..., 533. 4) deleting data on position 13, than shifting all indices in L to the left. So the new L is 144, 70000, 33,...532, 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you should not expect to be able to do this as most [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) implementations are not ordered, but Python's is [since 3.6](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/02/27/python-3-7-dictionaries-now-ordered/) and a part of the spec in 3.7 - but onto the question.

We can use a dictionary comprehension with [`enumerate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean) to make a new dictionary so we do not have to *worry* about the index shifting business that *worries* you.

```
L_ = set(L)
d = {k: v for i, (k, v) in enumerate(dict.items()) if i not in L_ and v}
```

Comment: This actually looks like what I'm actually looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary.keys()` and `dictionary.values()` both return indexable lists in python 2

As @grooveplex notes, in python 3, you can wrap each one with `list()` for the same effect

Comment: In Python 3, you could do `list(dictionary.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

I propose that instead of directly deleting the item, you update it with e.g. -1 and at the end you delete all -1 records

Comment: Therefore you run through the whole list and looking on each key 2 at least two times. Since the indices are not sorted even more.

Comment: @JürgenK. I do not understand. How is the sorting affected, when I update the value?