# How to add indices to a list?

Tags: python, list, indices

For example, I have a `list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.
What I want is a list `indexed(list) == [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c)]`.

Is there a builtin or module for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does enumerate() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)

Comment: No, this is asking from the definition of enumerate() for the function itself, while that is asking for the function of enumerate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to achieve that.

```
In [1]: a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [2]: b = [(idx, item) for idx,item in enumerate(a)]

In [3]: b
Out[3]: [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Note: the default indice would start with `0`, but you could try to add `start=1` to config that, e.g.

```
In [4]: c = [(idx, item) for idx,item in enumerate(a, start=1)]

In [5]: c
Out[5]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Enumerate takes an argument to change the starting index value if desired.

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate it by doing the following,

```
for i,n in enumerate(list):
# where i is the index and n is the value of the list
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
indexed_list = [(i + 1, elem) for i, elem in enumerate(your_list)]
```

I'm assuming that you need the index to start from 1. Otherwise you can just do a list comprehension on the `enumerate` results directly without adding 1 to the index.

EDIT: Updated according to @pault 's suggestion, i.e. using the built-in argument

```
indexed_list = [indexed for indexed in enumerate(your_list, 1)]
```

Or simply

```
indexed_list = list(enumerate(your_list, 1))
```

Comment: `enumerate` takes an optional argument that specifies thr index at which to start

Answer (score 3):

Indices in Python begin at `0` not `1`. You can do what you want by using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function along with the [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) generator function in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module.

It's also necessary to explicitly convert `zip()`'s result to a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) if that's what you want (which is why I changed the name of your variable to `my_list` to prevent it from "hiding" the built-in class with the same name — a good thing to *always* do):

```
from itertools import count

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

indexed_my_list = list(zip(count(), my_list))
print(indexed_my_list)  # -> [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

It's unclear why you would need to do this because you can use the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to get the indices whenever they're needed, as illustrated in a number of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Code below is what you want:

```py
>>>l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>>indl = [(i + 1, val) for i, val in enumerate(l)]
>>> indl
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Edit: according to @pault's suggestion, code is changed as below:

```py
>>> yourList = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> listInd = [(i, val) for i, val in enumerate(yourList, 1)]
>>> listInd
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
>>>
```

Comment: `enumerate` takes an optional argument that specifies thr index at which to start

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate and it's start argument for this too:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
indexed_list = list(enumerate(l, 1))
```

As for a function called `indexed` you could make one

**Note!** *Never replace a builtin keyword! `list` list is one of them*

```
>>> def indexed(l, start=1):
    ...    return list(enumerate(l, start))
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> indexed(l)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c)]
```

This defaults to a start value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension and enumerate

```
[(i,l) for i,l in enumerate(list)]
```