# Append to empty np array or assign new values for array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to either append to an empty array or overwrite/assign new values for all elements in an array. Here is my code:

```
initial_income = np.arange(N) # Initial Income
red_income = np.arange(N) # Reduced Initial Income

def reduce():
    global initial_income
    global red_income
    for i in initial_income:
        red_income = (i * 0.65) / 12
```

The issue is that I get back 5.362500000000001 -- the last result. How do I assign these new values to the existing red_income array?

Grateful for pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, value in enumerate(initial_income):
    red_income[i] = (value * 0.65) / 12
```

Or simply: `red_income = initial_income * 0.65 / 12`

For example:

```
>>> np.arange(10) * .65 / 12
array([ 0.        ,  0.05416667,  0.10833333,  0.1625    ,  0.21666667,
        0.27083333,  0.325     ,  0.37916667,  0.43333333,  0.4875    ])
```

Comment: Thanks...but i'm trying to understand. What does 'i, value' achieve?

Comment: @HenryP., for example: `list(enumerate([1,3,2,4])) == [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 4)]`. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean. `i, value` unpacks the individual tuples.