# How to find vowels in the odd positions of a string?

Tags: python

For my code, I have to make a function that counts the number of vowels in the odd positions of a string.

For example, the following will produce an output of 2.

```
st = "xxaeixxAU"
res = countVowelsOdd(st)
print (res)
```

For my code, the only problem I have is figuring out how to tell python to count the vowels in the **ODD** positions.

This is found in the second part of the "if statement" in my code where I tried to make the index odd by putting `st[i] %2 == 1`. I get all types of errors trying to fix this.

Any idea how to resolve this?

```py
def countVowelsOdd(st):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    count = 0
    for i, ch in enumerate(st):
        if i in vowels and st[i] % 2 == 1:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Shouldn't the count be _3_, not 2, here, because `U` is in the ninth position at the end of the input string?

Comment: Please, define ODD (people counts starting from one, Python counts starting from zero)

Answer (score 1):

```
if i in vowels ...
```

`i` is the index, you want the letter

```
if ch in vowels ...
```

and then since you have the index, that is what you find the modulo on

```
if ch in vowels and i % 2 == 1:
```

Comment: No I already completed the part where it counts vowels anywhere spotted in the string. I need help with the second part which is counting the vowels in odd positions of the string.

Comment: because `st[i]` is a letter within the string (the same letter as `ch`), you can't find the modulo of a letter

Comment: So "i" on it's own means just any number/position of a string?

Comment: [What does enumerate mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22171558/1324033) - i is the variable you've assigned to the index enumerate returns

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` provides you first argument `i` as position.

```py
def countVowelsOdd(st):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    count = 0
    for i, ch in enumerate(st):
        if ch in vowels and i % 2 == 1:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: You want to check if `ch` is in `vowels`.
`if ch in vowels`, not `if i in vowels`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your assignment/project precludes the use of regex, but if you are open to it, here is one option.  We can first do a regex replacement to remove all even-positioned characters from the input.  Then, do a second replacement to remove all non-vowel characters.  Finally, what remains gives us correct vowel count.

```
st = "xxaeixxAU"
st = re.sub(r'(.).', '\\1', st)
print(st)
st = re.sub(r'[^aeiou]', '', st, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(len(st))
```

This prints:

```
xaixU
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, have a look at this

```
In [1]: a = '01234567'                                                                    

In [2]: print(*(c for c in a[0::2]))                                                       
0 2 4 6

In [3]: print(*(c for c in a[1::2]))                                                      
1 3 5 7

In [4]: print(*(c in '12345' for c in a[1::2]))                                           
True True True False

In [5]: print(sum(c in '12345' for c in a[1::2]))                                         
3
```

does it help with your problem?