# Python3 - list index out of range - extracting data from file

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to extract data from a file and change the value of an entry with a 'for-loop'.

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\Measurement\LOGGNSS.txt", "r")
x=0
content = [[],[]]
for line in f:
    actualline = line.strip()
    content.append(actualline.split(","))
    x+=1
f.close

print(x)
for z in range(x):
    print(z)
    print(content[z][1])
```

*IndexError: list index out of range*

Using a real value instead of the variable 'z' works fine. But I need to change all first entries in the whole 2D-Array. 
Why it does not work?

Comment: `f.close` doesn't close the file BTW.

Comment: content contains empty lists at first. Those will fail with out of range index right away.

Comment: "Using a real value instead of the variable 'z' works fine" what do you mean? values 0 and 1 are guaranteed to fail because your list of lists starts by empty lists.

Comment: I have a file with over 80k rows. So using a 5 or 70000 instead of z i get access.

Comment: 5 or 70,000 would avoid the two empty arrays at the start of your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems.
First of all, use the [with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for) to open/close files correctly.
Then, you don't need to use a variable like `x` to keep track of the number of lines, just use [enumerate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean) instead!

Here is how I would refactor your code to make it slimmer and more readable.

```
input_file = r"C:\Users\Measurement\LOGGNSS.txt"
content = []

with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        clean_line = line.strip().split(",")
        content.append(clean_line)

for z, data in enumerate(content):
    print(z,'\n',data)
```

Note that you could print the content while reading the file in one single loop.

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    for z, line in enumerate(f):
        clean_line = line.strip().split(",")
        content.append(clean_line)
        print(z,'\n', clean_line)
```

Finally, if you are dealing with a plain and simple csv file, then use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from the standard library.

```
import csv

with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your content with two empty arrays, so both of these will fail to find the first index (`[1]`), just initialize it with an empty array

```
content = []
```

Comment: @Mat - Id suggest looking up what is in that row, I'm guessing an empty line.