# How to move values from one list to another while removing them from the first list

Tags: python, list

I have a simple program here in which I am trying to move numbers from `listA` to `listB` if their values are higher than 10. But how can I remove it from `listA` after it has moved to listB?

```
listA = [1,3,10,12,50,52]
listB = []
for i in range(len(listA)):
    val = listA[i]
    if val > 10:
        listB.append(val)
print(listA, listB)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the 'del' keyword. i.e., `del listA[i]`.
However, you shouldn't do this for 2 reasons:

1. Deleting a random element from a list is not efficient
2. You shouldnt mutate the list while you are iterating over it. Here is what happens if I modify the list while iterating over it, notice it doesn't see 2 elements!

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for i, x in enumerate(a):
...   print(x)
...   del a[i]
... 
1
3
```

It would better to create a temporary list, say tmp_listA, append to it, then replace it to the original. Don't modify the original.

Here is what that would look like:

```
listA = [1,3,10,12,50,52]
listB = []
tmpA = []
for i in range(len(listA)):
    val = listA[i]
    if val > 10:
        listB.append(val)
    else:
        tmpA.append(val)

listA = tmpA
print(listA, listB)
```

Comment: This is way different than what i wrote though

Comment: haha you're right, I just provided a snippet to illustrate the point. Modified the answer to make it more helpful now, hopefully.

Comment: Sure! Hope you look into the enumerate keyword, makes the code more readable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171593/4233629

Answer (score 2):

To give an alternative way:

````
listA = [1,3,10,12,50,52]
listB = [x for x in listA if not x>10]
listA = [x for x in listA if x>10]

print(listB)
# [1, 3, 10]

print(listA)
# [12, 50, 52]
```
````

Comment: although its solving the purpose, its still keeping the original list and memory associated. Question is to remove the elements

Answer (score 2):

I would use a simple list comprehension.

```
listA = [1, 3, 10, 12, 50, 52]

listB = [item for item in listA if item > 10]
listA = [item for item in listA if item not in listB]

print(listA, listB)
#[1, 3, 10] [12, 50, 52]
```

Comment: Switch the first and second list comprehension, and sir, we've got a problem. I'd not overwrite the original list.

Comment: You don't have to switch them, the code is procedural. The OP wants listA to be changed. So, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Guess you are right. OP wants the original list to be altered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `list.remove(value)`

```
listA = [1,3,10,12,50,52,2,10,3,34]
listB = []

for i in range(len(listA)):
    if listA[i] > 10:
        listB.append(listA[i])

for val in listB:
    listA.remove(val)

print(listA, listB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple more readable, straight forward way.

```
listA = [1,3,10,12,50,52]
listB = []
listA2 = []

for val in listA:
    if val > 10:
        listB.append(val)
    else:
        listA2.append(val)

listA = listA2

print(listA, listB)
```

Output:

[1, 3, 10] [12, 50, 52]

Comment: @Chubee updated the code without enumerate cloud be another way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

Here is your program a bit simplified and removing those values:

```
listA = [1, 3, 10, 12, 50, 52]
listA2 = listA.copy()
listB = []
for val in listA2:
    if val > 10:
        print(val)
        listB.append(val)
        listA.remove(val)
print(listA, listB)

[1, 3, 10] [12, 50, 52]
```

Comment: listA still has 50?

Comment: it will fail at runtime, as indexes keep decreasing.