# How does this python enumerate script work and what makes it so fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumeration

I found this example script on Leetcode supposed to find two values from a list that add up to the target number (always with 1 correct answer available upon input) but I've never used enumerate and don't know what it does. Can someone please help?

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        empty={}
        for index, number in enumerate(nums):
            if target-number in empty:
                return [empty[target-number],index]
            empty[number]=index
```

Comment: What does google say about python enumerate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does enumerate() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for `enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)?